# Destructuring json by key type

Tags: python

I have the following json:

```
{
  "Random.Int1": [50, 60, 1],
  "Random.Int2": [100, 200, 5],
  "Random.Int4": [30, 80, 10],
  "Items": {
    "tags": ["Random.Int5", "Random.Int6", "Random.Int7"],
    "params": [10, 20, 5]
  }
}
```

How can I deconstruct it to separate list and dict data, like:

```
list = [
    ["Random.Int1", [50, 60, 1]],
    ["Random.Int2", [100, 200, 5]],
    ["Random.Int4", [30, 80, 10]]
]

dict = {
    "Items": {
        "tags": ["Random.Int5", "Random.Int6", "Random.Int7"],
        "params": [10, 20, 5]
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to write a function that does that, is the short answer.  You'll need to clearly define what criteria control what ends up in the list_result, and what ends up in the dict_result. Side note: don't use `list` and `dict` as names in your program - doing so will shadow built-ins and cause you problems later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question states "by key type", but all keys are `str`, so I suspect you mean "by value type"

```
json_data ={
  "Random.Int1": [50, 60, 1],
  "Random.Int2": [100, 200, 5],
  "Random.Int4": [30, 80, 10],
  "Items": {
    "tags": ["Random.Int5", "Random.Int6", "Random.Int7"],
    "params": [10, 20, 5]
  }
}

my_list = [[key, value] for key, value in json_data.items() if isinstance(value, list)]
my_dict = {key:value for key, value in json_data.items() if isinstance(value, dict)}
print(my_list)
print(my_dict)
```

output

```
[['Random.Int1', [50, 60, 1]], ['Random.Int2', [100, 200, 5]], ['Random.Int4', [30, 80, 10]]]
{'Items': {'tags': ['Random.Int5', 'Random.Int6', 'Random.Int7'], 'params': [10, 20, 5]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a `dict`, assign the "Items" value and delete from the original data. Then iterate through the data's key/value pairs. Those come to you as tuples, so you need to turn them into lists as you go.

```
data = {
  "Random.Int1": [50, 60, 1],
  "Random.Int2": [100, 200, 5],
  "Random.Int4": [30, 80, 10],
  "Items": {
    "tags": ["Random.Int5", "Random.Int6", "Random.Int7"],
    "params": [10, 20, 5]
  }
}

mydict = {"Items": data["Items"]}
del data["Items"]
mylist = list(list(item) for item in data.items())

print(mylist)
print(mydict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume, the **dict key** is of type **int**, when you call it "Random.Intx", so one solution would look like this:

```
initial_dict: Dict[Union[int, Any], Union[List, Dict]] # to clarify typing



list_ = [
    [key, initial_dict[key]] for key in initial_dict \
    if isinstance(key, int)
]

dict_ = {
    key: initial_dict[key] for key in initial_dict \
    if not isinstance(key, int)
}



assert len(list_) + len(dict_) == len(initial_dict)
```